# Parse an Xml documents and make an Array with some Xml's Values

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

First of all, please accept my apologizes for the text. I am french, and it would not be "strange" there are some mistakes in my syntax.

Keep in mind too i am a "newbie" on the objective C world and programming.

So to explain you the problem i am actually in, i need to parse an xml, pick up some informations from it, (put them on an array or a dictionnary) and display them on a view.

this is the kind of Xml i have to parse : [XML](http://www.logaviv.com/xml/Euronext%20Bl%C3%A9.xml)

So as you can see, you have in this Xml several "echeances" tags. In them you have the previous ten dates and in those dates, you have differents values.

What i have to display at the end ? The tags "Settle" and "Variation" of the nearest date (the first one in the "list") for EACH "echeance" tag. (I also need to pickup the Attribute "nom=" for each "echeance".

Actually i've learned to use the "MVC" coding, and i have some troubles with the "Model" part.

I use Xcode 4.2 and use (i try ...) to use the ARC mode.

So let me see what i have done for the moment

The .h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Echeances.h"

@interface XMLToObjectParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> 

{
    NSMutableString *settle;
    NSMutableString *settle2;
    NSMutableString *change;
    NSMutableArray *lstEcheance;   
    NSString *currentNodeName;
    NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
    NSMutableDictionary *dico;
    NSMutableArray *settleArray;
    NSMutableArray *expiryArray;
    NSMutableArray *changeArray;
    NSString *expiryName;
    int compteur;
    Echeance *ech;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *expiryArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *settleArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *changeArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Echeance *ech;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *expiryName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *settle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *settle2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *change;





- (NSMutableArray *)expiry;

- (id)parseXMLAtURL:(NSURL *)url toObject:(NSString *)echeance parseError:(NSError **)error;


@end
```

The .m :

```
#import "XMLToObjectParser.h"


@implementation XMLToObjectParser

@synthesize expiryArray;
@synthesize settleArray;
@synthesize changeArray;
@synthesize currentNodeContent;
@synthesize ech;
@synthesize expiryName;
@synthesize settle;
@synthesize settle2;
@synthesize change;


- (NSMutableArray *)expiry

{
    return expiryArray;

}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)dico

{
    return dico;
}

- (id)parseXMLAtURL:(NSURL *)url toObject:(NSString *)aExpiryName parseError:(NSError **)error
{

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];


    if([parser parserError] && error) 
    {
        *error = [parser parserError];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict


{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"echeance"]) 

    {

        ech.nomEcheance = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"nom"];

        [expiryArray addObject:ech.nomEcheance];

        NSLog(@"%@", expiryArray);

    }


}   

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"settle"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"variation"]) 

    {

        for(int i = 0; i < [expiryArray count]; i++)
        {
            [settleArray addObject:currentNodeContent];
            NSLog(@"settle Array: %@",[settleArray lastObject]);
        }


    }


}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

{   

    [currentNodeContent setString:string];

}



@end
```

And as you can bet on it ... It does not work.

The thing i really want to do is to make a dictionnary with the attribute "nom=" of "echeance" tag as KEY of my dictionnary and each key associated to the correct settle and variation as explain at the top my topic.

To finish, i would like to thanks all the persons who will try to help me :)

Thanks for reading.

Romain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle of NSXMLParserDelegate is the combination of didStartElement(), foundCharacters() and didEndElement():

Echaence-Object has:

- nom
- settleArray as a mutable array

parseXMLAtUrl:

- Create a dictionary object

didStartElement:

- Found element 'echeance' => create new object Echeance and store it in Dictionary. Keep pointer to object for further actions in a private property.
- found element 'settle' => store flag, we're in settle-mode

foundCharacters:

- if in settle_mode => add string to current Echeance-Object's settleArray

didEndElement:

- found element 'settle' => delete flag, we're in settle-mode